# Correct way to return different objects on a java spring boot api?

Tags: spring-mvc

Consider the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/somePath")
public ResponseEntity someResource(
        @RequestParam(value = "number") int number
) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        case 2:
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("ok", "but with map");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(map);
        default:
            return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
    }
}
```

This way I can return custom payloads with different http status, but my IDE keeps me warning: `Raw use of parameterized class 'ResponseEntity'`. If I define a type, I lose this customization. What is the recommended way of achieving this behavior?

Comment: Use at least ResponseEntity<?>. You can replace "?" by the wished type (as String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments by @jlh91, I was satisfied with `ResponseEntity<?>` on the main method and for each case, its method would return `ResponseEntity<String>` or `ResponseEntity<Integer>`